# How to define function that takes the most generic number and types of parameters

Tags: c++

How can I redefine this function:

```
unsigned int uiTimer(int milliseconds, int (*f)(void *data), void *data)
```

so that it can take this function as a param (or any other function regardless of signature) ?

```
int filterInput(uiEditableCombobox *pBox, void *pvData)
```

like this:

```
uiTimer(1000, filterInput, NULL);
```

I tried wrapping filterInput in a "timerDone(void *)" but this cannot be done because I need to pass the parameters into filterInput.

```
int timerDone(void *) {
    filterInput();  // <--- I need context to be passed as params
}
uiTimer(1000, timerDone, NULL);
```

Comment: If you are using at least C++11 you should look at [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind). Also change the second parameter in `uiTimer` from a C-style function pointer to `std::function<int(void*)>`. Do not use `void*` at all, use templates instead!

Comment: @hellow: generics -> templates, the former is the very much poorer Java cousin.

Comment: @hellow also `std::bind` is the ugly brother of lambdas that most of the time you dont need

Comment: What a great family.

Comment: @Bathsheba I do find many people use "generics" to refer to template, those are also very likely to use "stl" for standard library. Maybe it's not from Java influence, but rather an old habitude.

Answer (score 2):

Change signature to use [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function):

```
#include <functional>
unsigned int uiTimer(int milliseconds, std::function<int(void*)> f, void *data)
```

Pass parameters using [lambda expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

```
uiEditableCombobox *box;
uiTimer(1000, [=](void* data) { return filterInput(box, data); }, nullptr);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can take any function pointer as argument this way:

```
template<typename R, typename... Ts>
void f(R(*functionPointer)(Ts...))
{ /* ... */ }
```

Unfortunately, separate case is necessary for member function pointers:

```
template<typename R, typename T, typename... Ts>
void f(R(T::*functionPointer)(Ts...))
{ /* ... */ }
```

But in essence, any function pointer will be also caught by single template parameter since it's also a valid type, but then you must be aware that you are allowing much more entities to be passed (e.g. not a function pointers).

```
template<typename T>
void f(T&& f)
{ /* ... */ }
```

Here is a working example that shows mutiple ways of using function pointers in template functions: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a1a01993266e6351

Comment: I'm not sure why you need a special case for member pointers. Are you familiar with [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) ?

Comment: Because it's a different kind of function pointer, which needs a "this" pointer passed as argument implicitly:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/26ac554632851f2a
That's why additional overload is necessary:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/85d3d514d323bfeb

Calling function from function pointer was just an example, I'm aware of ```std::invoke``` ; ).

Comment: I htikn you're missing my point there. You don't need an overload for member functions, because you don't call them directly. You farm out the special handling of `this` to a Standard Library component, either ` std::invoke` or `std::function`.